# "if elsif end if" versus two "if end if" concatenated in VHDL. Which syntax makes the most optimized circuit logic?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

[image]

- Let's assume an entity has an input signal called i_x: std_logic
- Let's assume this i_x can take just 2 possible values: '0' or '1'.
- Let's say the entity has an output signal called o_x: std_logic
- Let's say o_x must be the opposite of i_x:

Code A)

```
    if (i_x='0') then
      o_x <='1';
    elsif (i_x='1') then
      o_x<='0'

    end if;
```

Code B)
(edited)

```
if (i_x='1') then    
o_x<='0';    
end if;

if (i_x='0') then    
o_x<='1';    
end if;
```

Is either of the aforementioned structures better than the other for synthesis, implementation purposes, and the generation of an eventual bitstream for an FPGA?

I would say the alternative B) is better because no priorities are involved compared to the elsif structure and therefore code B makes the circuit logic smaller than code A. Anyway I am not sure whether I am right or not. Can anyone confirm it?

Which syntax makes the most optimized circuit logic?

Comment: Have you tried synthesizing the logic and seeing what elements are instantiated? Chances are, all of this fits inside a single LUT anyway.

Comment: None. Both of them should generate the same hardware. A flip flop with an lut.

Comment: I did not try synthesizing the logic. I just asked this because I think I read somewhere that code with prioritized cases such as the alternative A of my question must be avoided if possible to make a more optimized circuit logic.

Comment: They should produce the same logic. But the first one is 100% the correct style to use instead of the two separated 'if's, which is a major 'no'.

Comment: @MituRaj I know the OP says this is an FPGA and not an ASIC as the target. But how does an FF get inferred from the first case the OP mentions. (The second case just duplicates the same thing twice so I'm not addressing it.) All input cases are covered and so it looks like a MUX, doesn't it?

Comment: @goahead97 The first case, given my hobbyist-level understanding of things, presents every possible case for i_x (it can only be a 0 or a 1) and always specifies an output so there's no need to hold a value and is therefore a mux (which I suppose can be optimized into a NOT if this targeted an ASIC.) I don't see any need for sequential (FF) logic to be inferred from it. Your second case duplicates the same thing twice (I do not know why you did that.) But ignoring that problem and since the conditional doesn't include all cases for the output you want, an FF is always inferred, I believe.

Comment: @jonk you are right it could be a mux or more accurately an inverter in LUT if this was inside a combinational process, otherwise a flop with LUT.

Comment: You may have a copy paste error on CODE B.

Comment: fixed the copy paste error - if they approve my edits :)

Comment: @goahead97 I like sbell's third example better -- which is "none of the above" in your examples. You can't screw up with it. It starts right out with the default (which means ***all cases*** are covered right away) and then modifies this with a specific case. You won't get an FF inferred, accidentally, that way.

Answer (score 3):

To the tools, it makes no difference which way you write it.   To the humans it certainly does as people regularly misunderstand what the multiple, separate if statements actually do.

First consider your case, corrected so that both match.

**Code A:  Inverter with If then else**

```
if (i_x='0') then
  o_x <='1';
elsif (i_x='1') then
  o_x<='0'
end if;
```

From a hardware perspective, this code is equivalent to:

```
if (i_x='0') then
  o_x <='1';
else
  o_x<='0'
end if;
```

**Code B:  Inverter with If then end if**
I am updating your segments of code so they are not the same and ordering them to be consistent with my follow on code:

```
CodeB : process (i_x)
begin
  if (i_x='1') then
    o_x<='0';
  end if;

  if (i_x='0') then
    o_x<='1';
  end if;
end process CodeB ;
```

**Code C:  Inverter done directly**
At the end of the day, the tools should see your
code as follows:

```
o_x <= not i_x ;
```

**Modifying the problem statement to see the differences**
To illustrate the subtle difference between if then elsif and separate if then end if, lets add more signals to the equation.   Lets consider some priority select logic:

**Code A:  Priority select logic with If then else**
The following logic selects A, B, or C, when the appropriate
enable is selected.   Note it it is not and-or logic, but instead
often implemented by a cascade of multiplexors.  As the number of
Sel signals increases the quality of hardware decreases - but
for this number it is generally not an issue (in a LUT based FPGA).

```
CodeAPrioritySel : process (SelA, A, SelB, B, SelC, C) is 
begin
  if    (SelA = '1') then
    Y <= A ; 
  elsif (SelB = '1') then
    Y <= B ; 
  elsif (SelC = '1') then
    Y <= C ; 
  else
    Y <= "XX" ; 
  end if;
end process CodeAPrioritySel ;
```

**Code B:  Priority select logic with If then end if**

```
CodeBPrioritySel : process (SelA, A, SelB, B, SelC, C) is 
begin
  Y <= "XX" ; 
  if (SelC = '1') then
    Y <= C ; 
  end if;
  if (SelB = '1') then
    Y <= B ; 
  end if;
  if (SelA = '1') then
    Y <= A ; 
  end if;
end process CodeBPrioritySel ;
```

Note, to get the equivalent circuit to CodeAPrioritySel I wrote
the if statements in the opposite order.

Don't trust my word on this?  Ok, try this,
mentally (or in your favorite simulator)
run the both sets of code with SelA = 1, SelB = 0,
and SelC = 1 and initialize A, B, C to different values.
Note that is why I implied that they are array values
rather than bit values (ie: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)).
In either case you get Y = A.   Remember the
rule for signal assignments in a process when time is not
passing is that the last executed assignment wins - which
is true for everything that creates RTL hardware.

Comment: Thy funky thing about the *CodeBPrioritySel* example is that if the "Y <= "XX";" line is deleted then a latch must be inferred. And the same thing is also still true with the *CodeAPrioritySel* example, if the final "else" clause is forgotten about. Without changing their intent and between just those two example choices you presented, which do you feel can be more reliably read, modified, and maintained over time? (I think I'll agree with you, but I also think this may be something that one group might chose differently than another. So I'm curious about your opinion.)

Comment: I think CodeAPrioritySel is easier to read and maintain.   As you saw in the "comments" to the post, some think CodeBPrioritySel does not have priority.   That is a problem.   Good code should be readable.

Comment: WRT latches, in my statemachines where we have lots of case and if, I recommend assigning all of your outputs to the non-active value at the beginning of the process (before any case or if) and then only assign the active value in the remainder code.   With that you get two benefits:  no latches and shorter code - which I think for a statemachine is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I'm just a hobbyist and work entirely for my own fun. No team to talk these things over with. Just books I read when I need to know something. I'm ready for hearing opinions like this and it's nice to get yours. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually *three* canonical ways to represent what you're doing:

### Code A

```
if (i_x='0') then
    o_x <='1';
elsif (i_x='1') then
    o_x<='0'
end if;
```

### Code B (corrected)

```
if (i_x='1') then
    o_x<='0';
end if;

if (i_x='0') then
    o_x<='1';
end if;
```

### Code C

```
o_x<='0';
if (i_x='0') then
    o_x<='1';
end if;
```

In a VHDL process, order is important, even with a signal: **the last value assigned to a signal is given priority**.  (Things are different with variables)

So, in Code A, the priority is explicitly given to the first if statement and there's nothing else to worry about.

In Code B, priority is given to the second if statement (because it comes later in the code); if the second 'if' statement is true o_x will be assigned '1', no matter what happened before that point.

In Code C, the same is true: priority is given to the if statement because it follows the always assignment. Should the if statement trigger, o_x will be assigned '1'.